# for loop replacing old array with the same input, how do I fix this?

Tags: java

I am trying to save all x values into xCoord and all y values to yCoord so I can try to connect them with a line later, but every time I try to append to the arrays it just replaces the old values with the new ones.

```
while (counter < 2) {
    int[] xCoord = new int[5];
    int[] yCoord = new int[5];
    System.out.println("Enter x coordinate:");
    int newX = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter y coordinate:");
    int newY = sc.nextInt();
    gc.setFill(Color.RED);
    gc.fillRect(newX, newY, 10, 10);
    gc.setStroke(Color.YELLOW);
    gc.strokeLine(newX, newY, newY * 2, newX * 2);
    counter++;
    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
        xCoord[i] = newX;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
        yCoord[i] = newY;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(xCoord));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(yCoord));
}
```

Output:

```
    Enter x coordinate:
    100
    Enter y coordinate:
    100
    [100, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    [100, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    Enter x coordinate:
    200
    Enter y coordinate:
    222
    [200, 200, 0, 0, 0]
    [222, 222, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to add a new entry to each array on each iteration of the loop? If so the logic can be made a lot simpler.

Couple issues with your version:

1) You are creating new arrays on each iteration of the loop, meaning everything assigned in the previous iteration is lost.

2) Your for loops within the while loop start from 0, so on every iteration of the while loop, your for loops are rewriting each entry in both arrays.

Here is what I would do:

```
int num_coordinates = 5;
int counter = 0;

int [] xCoord = new int [num_coordinates];
int [] yCoord = new int [num_coordinates];

while ( counter < num_coordinates ) {
    System.out.println("Enter x coordinate:");
    int newX = sc.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter y coordinate:");
    int newY = sc.nextInt();

    gc.setFill(Color.RED);
    gc.fillRect(newX,newY,10,10);
    gc.setStroke(Color.YELLOW);
    gc.strokeLine(newX, newY, newY*2, newX*2);

    xCoord[counter] = newX;
    yCoord[counter] = newY;

    counter++;

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(xCoord));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(yCoord));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are looping through and setting all the array values to the new value with your for loops here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
    xCoord[i] = newX;
}
for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
    yCoord[i] = newY;
}
```

You should be just using the counter as the array index instead of looping through it all.

```
xCoord[counter] = newX;
yCoord[counter] = newY;
```

Also, you need to take your declaration of the arrays outside of your while loop or else it will keep wiping the data each iteration.